# Fastest way of reading file into OS file cache

Tags: java, nio

I am looking for the fastest way of reading a file - I don't need to see the read bytes, I just need the file to be fully read so that it gets in the OS file cache.

This is what I am using at the moment (but it involves allocating a direct buffer for each file)

```
   FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream( file );
   FileChannel ch = f.getChannel( );
   ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int)file.length() );
   ch.read(bb);
```

Comment: your current implementation is buggy - what if the file is 1G in size - your buffer allocation will fail, Instead allocate a buffer of reasonable size X and read your file in a loop. 


PS: Why on earth you want the file in cache ? even if you load it, there is absolutely no guarantee that it will still be there when you need it

Comment: Yes, good point. I have corrected it in my code.  Why am I doing this? Because I have a java library that uses NIO to transfer files from DVD over a socket. For some reason, it is very slow when transfering from DVD, but extremely fast when the file is in the windows files cache. So, my solution is to read 50 MB of files, then transfer them using the library (when I am pretty sure they are cached).

Comment: well, the total time (from dvd -> to cache + from cache -> other end of connection)  will still be roughly the same, because (as I understanded you) the bottleneck is the reading from the dvd.

Comment: Whether it helps the total throughput or not. How about using MappedByteBuffer and reading just one byte in each OS disk block. That might force all the bytes into memory, because the OS always read the full block of 512 or is it 4096 bytes on your Windows?

Comment: @Harald the problem with MappedByteBuffer is that I have to allocate one per file, and there are thousands of files. So, this may cause memory heap thrash.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to EJPs suggestion, I created my own /dev/null file channel:

```
   RandomAccessFile racFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
   FileChannel ch = racFile.getChannel( );
   ch.transferTo(0,  fileLength, new WritableByteChannel(){

    @Override
    public boolean isOpen() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public int write(ByteBuffer src) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int rem = src.remaining();
        return rem;
    }

   }

   );
   racFile.close();
```

This provided the fastest solution in my benchmarks.

Comment: That wasn't my suggestion. The operating system already provides such a device. There is no need to write code to accomplish this, as I said in my answer. And if you do, just copy the data to that device. You don't have to invent your own.

Comment: Yes, I do have to invent my own. Your suggestion did not work. This is the best solution I could find.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy it to `/dev/null` with `cat,` or `\nul` with `copy` on Windows. No need to write any code at all.

Comment: Thanks, EJP. Your suggestion triggered the idea that solved it for me. However, launching a process for each file doesn't seem optimal to me.

Comment: @Jacko I didn't say anything about a process per file. Both these programs can copy multiple files per invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using memory mapped files: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html and http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/683614/10-Things-to-Know-about-Memory-Mapped-File-in-Java. On Unix you can also map them in command line, not sure about Windows.